# Spreadsheet- How to update the value of the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I want to update the value of a the cell based on the current value of that cell and value of another cell like `A1=A1+A2`what is the correct formula

Answer (score 1):

**You can use either of the Solutions shown below:**

**Solution 1:**

- Click **File** Menu then below you find 
  **Options**  click it and you find new screen.
- Click **Formula Tab** and check the **Enable 
  Iterative Calculation**, and set **Maximum 
  Iteration** (currently is 1).

[image]

- Write this Formula in Cell `A1`: `=A1+A2`.

[image]

- Write Value in Cell `A2` for example `5`.

[image]

- Press `F9`:

[image]

**Note:** Every time you get new value, after `F9` been pressed.

**Solution 2:**

- From the sheet, press `Alt+F11` to open VB 
  editor.
- **Copy & Paste** this code as `Standard Module`.

  ```
    Public Sub Calcloop()

      For i = 1 To 1

       Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + Range("A2").Value

      Next i

    End Sub
  ```
- From **File** menu click `Close & Return to MS- 
  Excel`.
- **RUN** the Macro.

**Note:**

- Initially you find `0` in cell `A1`.
- Now put some value like `5` in cell `A2` and 
  **Run** the Macro, you find  New Value.
- Every time you get new value as soon you 
  **RUN** the Macro.

**N.B.**

- For **Solution 1**, `Maximum Iteration` 
  value is editable, if you set it to `5`, 
  then Excel  will recalculate the Formula 
  5 times.
- Likewise for the **Solution 2**, in shown 
  Macro, `For i = 1 To 1` is also editable, 
  you may set the `For Loop` according to 
  your need, for example, `For i = 1 To 5`, 
  recalculates the Formula 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done natively in Excel, as the formula creates a circular reference, but it can be done using VBA. If you want the value calculated when you click a button, you can add a button from the control section of the developer tab, and then assign a macro to it. In the below example I've called the button 'Button1'. Then in the Visual Basic editor, add the following subroutine to the 'This Workbook' object.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + Range("A2").Value

End Sub
```

To assign a macro to the button, right click on the button, click 'Assign Macro' and the macro 'ThisWorkbook.Button1_Click' should be listed. Select this macro and click ok. The value in A2 will be added to the value in A1.

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, @GooberZoober don't you think that you have just copied my **Solution 2**, the VBA (Macro).

Comment: @Rajesh S yes it is similar to your answer, you were quicker to post a solution than I was! I still think that my answer has value though, as it is simpler than creating a loop (the OP may not need to calculate this value more than once at a time) and it mentions adding a button to run the macro, which is quicker and easier than running the macro through the menu options.

Comment: My humble suggestion is, coping answer is not a good practice, so edit your post and show method different than mine,, will help OP and the community also. And basically my code Calculates Formula ONCE Only since Loop is to do so,, and I've posted my suggestion also,, how to improve !!

Comment: I didn't copy your answer though, there wasn't any answer provided when I started answering the question, and it is a different way of calculating, though still using VBA. Yes, your code only calculates it once, but if you didn't need the option to iterate through more than once, my code is simpler. I think both answers provide good content.